# refereshToken is empty aws-amplify javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-sign-on, aws-amplify, aws-config

I use aws-amplify as shown below,

```
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
   
    region: config.aws.region,


    identityPoolRegion: config.aws.region,

    userPoolId: process.env.userPoolId,

    userPoolWebClientId: process.env.appClientId,


    oauth: {
      domain: process.env.domain,
      //  scope: ['phone', 'email', 'profile', 'openid', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'],
      redirectSignIn: `${process.env.redirectSignIn}`,
      redirectSignOut: process.env.redirectSignout,
      responseType: code // NOTE: It was set to 'token' earlier and I used to get accessToken/IDToken back but refreshToken was empty
    }
  }
});
```

As you can see `responseType` was set to `token` and I was able to do microsoft SSO login successfully. I used to get AccessToken/IdToken in redirect URL but `refreshtoken` as always empty.

I want to generate `refershToken` to refresh session at later stage.

To get a `refreshtoken`, I saw I need to change `responseType` to `code` as shown above,

**How I call to oauth2 endpoint (with responseType = code)**

```
const azureLogin = () => {
    window.location.href = `https://${process.env.domain}/oauth2/authorize?identity_provider=${process.env.identityProviderName}&redirect_uri=${process.env.redirectSignIn}&response_type=${process.env.responseType}&client_id=${process.env.appClientId}&scope=aws.cognito.signin.user.admin+email+openid+phone+profile`;
  };
```

From my app, whenever I do (SSO) login it does following things,

browser's URL changes to something :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/62xxx-7x-4xxxf50-axx7-fxxx692/saml2?SAMLRequest=fZJbS8MwF********************
```

Then it changes to,

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/redirect?code=bccxxx-exx-4xx-8x-9xxxxxx
```

I get code but I don't what should I do with this code. how to use this code to get accessToken, IdToken and refreshToken?

Can someone pls help me with the flow?

PS: I checked AWS-amplify document also but flow is not clear. On top of it, there are no examples available which I can take help from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after above setup, you start getting code.

After getting code, you can get tokens by making a **HTTP POST** request as follow,

```
const getToken= (code: string) => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      body: new URLSearchParams({
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        code: `${code}`,
        client_id: `${process.env.appClientId}`,
        client_secret: `${process.env.secretHash}`,
        redirect_uri: `${process.env.redirectSignIn}`
      })
    };

    return fetch(`https://${process.env.domain}/oauth2/token`, requestOptions);

  }
```

As response, you get all tokens successfully.